# get json data by kotlin with retrofit2 from webservice(python flask)

Tags: android, json, web-services, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm developing an application in Kotlin that uses Retrofit 2 to call my web-service (python flask) and I found only an example with `@Query(action=query&format=json)`.  What I want is to get data from  a JSON array like this:

[image: JSONarray]

How to do it?

Comment: What is your issue exactly? To call your webservice, to transform the response into a JSON array, or something else? Could you also provide the code you wrote to reproduce your scenario?

Comment: @user2340612 in java I did something like this https://github.com/cr0nil/retrofit now, I want to do the same in kotlin

Comment: If you have a code that's already written in Java, you can convert it to Kotlin quite easy. Just open the java file in Android Studio and invoke action "Convert Java to Kotlin" (keyboard shortcut in macos: shift+alt+cmd+K)